# Status Code:404 Not Found (from cache) | Hybrid App using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm currently creating a hybrid mobile application.

While running the application on an Android emulator, I get the following error: Status Code:404 Not Found (from cache) in one $http.post request.

Below is the post request used in my code. The URL is of a local Tomcat server being used in my project.

```
var postData = {'loginId':$scope.user.id};

postData = $.param(postData);

$http({
     method: "POST",
     url: checkUserURL,
     data: postData,
     cache:false,
     headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;'
     }
});
```

When I place the url in href of an anchor tag inside the mobile application and click it, I get redirected to the mobile browser from where I'm able to hit the url and get the expected output.

I am able to access the url from my web browser too. The error occurs only when I try to use the $http request in the application.

Note: I've all the libraries needed included in my project.

Is it because of the format of the data I'm sending to the server?

Can you please let me know what could be the issue here and the possible resolution actions that can be taken?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because of the way you are passing your parameter. You don't have to use `$.param`. Try to pass a plain JavaScript object:

```
var postData = {
   loginId: $scope.user.id
};

$http({
     method: "POST",
     url: checkUserURL,
     data: postData,
     cache:false
});
```